# How to specify the full path of a newly created file in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Is there a package that will let me specify the full path of a file that hasn't been saved yet? I know I can use the AdvancedNewFile package to specify the full path where a file should be saved, but I would like to do the same for a file that has already been created (but not yet saved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and couldn't figure it out until browsing through the undocumented functions in sublime.py [eg from /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime.py on osx]

This works:

`view.retarget("/tmp/foo.txt")`

from: `def retarget(self, new_fname)` in class `View`

Comment: Ah, interesting. So, `Show Console` and then `view.retarget("/path/for/my/new.file")` and then `Save`